# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddIdentity'

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, ef-core-7.0

Before I tested this line on a web application in core 5.

```cs
services.AddIdentity<Operator, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<StorageContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This works fine in startup class.
Now I want to know how to implement it in windows form, Core 7. Because I just get this error -

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddIdentity'
> and no accessible extension method 'AddIdentity' accepting a first
> argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Am I missing assemblies? what are they?
this is my code now -

```cs
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddScoped<IStorageRepository, StorageRepository>();
            services.AddDbContext<StorageContext>(option =>
            {
                option.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
                option.UseSqlServer(configuration["Data:Storage:ConnectionString"]);
            });
            services.AddIdentity<Operator, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<StorageContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        });
}
```

Does this `AddIdentity` class works in Winforms?

Answer (score 1):

Just try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just try to add this nugget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI. I add it and it start see it